# Solve the equation over reals: $\sqrt{5x^2 + 27x + 25} - 5\sqrt{x + 1} = \sqrt{x^2 - 4}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, substitution

> Solve the equation over reals: $\sqrt{5x^2 + 27x + 25} - 5\sqrt{x + 1} = \sqrt{x^2 - 4}$.

This problem is adapted from a recent competition. And I can't solve it.

The solutions are $\sqrt{5} + 1$ and $\dfrac{13 + \sqrt{65}}{8}$, as Wolfram Alpha says.

Comment: So you haven't tried squaring both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain gives $x\geq2$ and we need to solve 
$$\sqrt{5x^2+27x+25}=5\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-4}$$ or
$$5x^2+27x+25=25(x+1)+10\sqrt{(x+1)(x^2-4)}+x^2-4$$ or
$$2x^2+x+2=5\sqrt{(x^2-x-2)(x+2)}$$ or
$$\frac{2x^2}{x+2}+1=5\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x+2}-1}.$$
Now, take $$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x+2}-1}=t.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 3):

Writing $$\sqrt{5x^2+27x+25}=\sqrt{x^2-4}+5\sqrt{x+1}$$ and squaring we get
$$4x^2+2x+4=10\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x^2-4}$$ dividing by $2$ we get
$$2x^2+x+2=5\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x^2-4}$$
squaring again we obtain
$$4x^4+4x^3+9x^2+4x+4=25(x+1)(x^2-4)$$
expanding and combining like terms
$$4x^4-21x^3-16x^2+104x+104=0$$
This can be factorized as
$$\left( 4\,{x}^{2}-13\,x-26 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}-2\,x-4 \right) =0$$
Such factorization can be found by the following ansatz
$$(Ax^2+Bx+C)(ax^2+bx+c)=4x^4-21x^3-16x^2+104x+104$$
and comparing the coefficients.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you make it?

Comment: Because down-voting is much easier than computing by itself.

Comment: Sonnhard, I think the problem is much more  serious.